# hange decimal to => deg/min/sec for geography java

Tags: java

i have a problem here my eclipse don't recognize  the type Decimal in my code source !! i try to creat a tool that allow me to convert decimal coordinate to degrees minute and seconde !! please help me if you have some idea about this point !!

```
public class GeolocationDecimalToDegreesConverter{

    public static String convert(Decimal latitude, Decimal longitude){
        return convertLatitud(latitude) + ' ' + convertLongitude(longitude);
    }

    public static String convertLatitud(Decimal latitude){
        String result = "" ;
        if(latitude != null){
            String direction = "N";
            if(latitude < 0){
                direction = "S";
            }

            result = convert(latitude) + direction;
        }
        return result;
    }



    public static String convertLongitude(Decimal longitude){
        String result = "";
        if(longitude != null){
            String direction = "E";
            if(longitude < 0){
                direction = "W";
            }
            result = convert(longitude) + direction;
        }

        return result;
    }


    private static String convert(Decimal d){
        d = d.abs();
        //degrees

        Integer i = d.intValue();
        String s = String.valueOf(i) + '°';
        //minutes

        d = d - i;
        d = d * 60;
        i = d.intValue();
        s = s + String.valueOf(i) + '\'';

        //seconds

        d = d - i;
        d = d * 60;
        i = d.round().intValue();
        s = s + String.valueOf(i) + '"';
        return s;
    }
}
```

some solutions please

Comment: Where did you get this code?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in `Decimal` type in Java.

- So either it is defined in your code somewhere - then try to organize imports with `Ctrl-Shift-O`.
- Or it comes from some library. Organize imports would help here as well.

Or the code is simply and plainly invalid. Which would be my bet as I can't imagine `latitude < 0` to work for some third-party `Decimal` type.

Solution is simple: just use `java.math.BigDecimal` instead. You can't do `myBigDecimal < 0` but there's enough API to handle any math you need.